# How to detect special hidden files in Linux (e.g. .reiser_priv)?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I've recently found out that there are special hidden directories found on Linux that are not displayed with `ls -a` command. Namely the one I encountered is *.reiserfs_priv* directory located in the root of a reiserfs filesystem. I can call `ls -ld .reiserfs_priv` on it and `cd` into the directory (as root), but it is not shown with `ls -a` command (`find ./ -name *reiser*` doesn't find it as well).

Questions:

- How do I actually detect this kind of directories?
- Can I create them myself?
- What kind of mechanism do they use to stay *stealth* and why `ls -a` doesn't see them?
- Can it be files as well?
- Where these type of directories are generally used?

Comment: `find . -name *reiser*` won't find it because the shell ignores dot files when it expands the `*reiser*` glob. Try `find . -name '*reiser*'` with quotes instead. In a similar vein, did you try `ls -a` or `ls -a *reiser*`? The first should work but the second wouldn't.

Comment: @roaima No, that's not it. Under default configurations, all common shells would either leave `*reiserfs*` intact if there were no matches, or would signal an error and not run the command. Besides golem did mention trying `ls -a`, so the file is genuinely hidden from `readdir`.

Comment: @Gilles so we have files that can't be seen with `opendir`/`readdir` but exist with `open`. Fair enough; it's the same sort of semantics exposed by Samba for "hidden" files and directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot detect or create such files in general. They only exist because a filesystem is reporting inconsistent data.

In the absence of modifications to the filesystem, there are redundancies between various ways of obtaining information about the files on that filesystem. For example, permissions permitting:

- If a file name is reported by `readdir` then calling `lstat` on that name will succeed.
- If `lstat` does not report the file to be a symbolic link, then calling `stat` and `open` will also succeed.
- If `stat` succeeds then `open` succeeds`.
- If `open` succeeds then so do `stat` and `lstat`.
- If `stat` reports a file to be a directory then `cd` succeeds and vice versa.

And so on. When a Reiserfs filesystem omits the `.reiserfs_priv` entry from directory listings and yet reports it as a directory via system calls that access it directly, the filesystem is reporting inconsistent information.

This information isn't wrong, just inconsistent. It's only violating conventions, not rules. The same behavior could be observed if there was a very fast goblin who created that directory just before you ran `cd` or `ls .reiserfs_priv`, and removed it just before you ran `find`.

It is somewhat bad form for a filesystem to report inconsistent data, because that confuses some applications and users, so it should only be done for a very good reason. In the case of Reiserfs, the reason is to make some information rather hidden, and in particular not traversed by file searches and indexing. This is useful because the content of `.reiserfs_priv` is not “real” files, it's used to store [extended file attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes), which are accessed by calling the `*xattr` system call family. In fact, I don't know why it's exposed at all — maybe only for debugging purposes.

Another example of not reporting files that exist is filesystems that allow the same data to be returned in different ways. For example, [ciopfs](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/) presents a case-insensitive view of a filesystem; if you have a file called `Foo` then a directory listing will only list `Foo` but accessing `foo`, `FOO`, etc. will succeed.

Comment: Great explanation and nicely written. Thanks!